# How to pass a dynamic number of arguments to a function?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that could have a varying number of keys. The value of the keys is a list of numbers. I want to compare each of these lists and get the list that is the maximum of all of the items in the list.

built in max() function will give me the maximum of all the items if I passed it in the way below:

max(lista, listb, listc)

The number of lists varies and my dictionary looks something like this:

myDict = {1:lista,2:listb:3:listc,...}

I was thinking or something like this:

maxlist = max(for item in myDict.keys(): myDict[item])

But I don't think this works. Please help!

Comment: Not the best way to do it, but yours would have worked if you said ... maxlist = max([myDict[x] for x in myDict.keys()])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax of the generator expression would be

```
maxlist = max(myDict[item] for item in myDict.keys())
```

It would be much easier in this case to use `myDict.values()` in the first place:

```
maxlist = max(myDict.values())
```

Comment: This works for me also. I ended up using the generator expression because of the way I had the dictionary set up.

for band in aptData[file].keys():

  for channel in aptData[file][band].keys():

   for mode in aptData[file][band][channel].keys():

    txpwr = max(aptData[sample][band][channel][mode][0] for sample in aptData.keys())

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
>>> p = {1: [2,3], 4: [5,6,7]}
>>> max(p.values())
[5, 6, 7]
```

For dictionaries, `values()` returns the values so you don't explicitly need to iterate over all the key/values in the dictionary.

Comment: this works...didn't think it was this easy...i feel embarrassed :(

Answer (score 0):

given a dictionary spam, you can find the maximum as

```
max(spam.values(),key=len)
```

now your question is bit ambiguous in the sense as to what is that whose maximum you want to find

The above would return you the length of the list which have maximum elements (aka length is maximum)

If instead you want to get the maximum element of all the lists (the single max element) you can also do

```
max(itertools.chain(*spam.values()))
```

Instead if you want to find the list which has the maximum value you can do

```
max(spam.values())
```